# Communicating with HID-compliant device

Tags: c#, hid

I am sure I am in the wrong place but I don't know where to go!

---

I am trying to develop an application that will communicate with an **HID-compliant device**. 
I got a little information from the tech support of the `HID-compliant` device I am working with that told me I needed to use

> Finding and Opening an HID Collection Functions

Such as `HidD_getHidGuid`,  `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`, `SetupDiDeviceInterfaceDetail` and so forth.

---

The code development for this is proving to be a daunting task for me. I was wondering if there are any real-life code examples in C# that use these all at one time? I am trying to connect to a device and read the data from it. I am in a new job and have experience communicating serially through Comports but nothing like this. If anyone can help me, please.

Comment: Pinvoke.net has these functions, even an example of  usage, like here https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi.setupdigetclassdevs . Then googling for e.g. `c# SetupDiGetClassDevs site:github.com` shows some examples